# Submit results for different rows

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, roles

I have a problem here guys and I need your suggestions. The thing is that I created a code for a wordpress website in which a administrator is able to change roles of user from a page not the administrator dashboard. Now I have created the code and I am stuck in one place, the problem is that upon submit, the data should be changed for each and every user which has updated selected roles. But at the moment it only processes the last one in que. ***So the issue is that the role is not being updated for each different user and besides updating each the code only processes the last user in que.***

**Image Help**

[`var_dump`](http://take.ms/0wakm) results ...

**CODE:**

```
function custom_get_users() {
    require_once('wp-admin/includes/template.php');
    require_once('wp-includes/registration.php');
    if ( !function_exists('get_editable_roles') ) {
     require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/user.php' );
    }
    global $current_user;
    global $wp_roles;
    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
    $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);

    if ( is_user_logged_in() && $user_role == 'administrator' ) {

    $args = array(
        'orderby'      => 'ID',
        'order'        => 'ASC',
    );
    $blogusers = get_users( $args );


    if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
        $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
        $new_role = $_POST['userRole'];
        var_dump($user_id);
        var_dump($new_role);
        // update user role using wordpress function
        wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $user_id, 'role' => $new_role ) ) ;
    }


    echo "<form method='post' action='#'>";
    echo "<table class='widefat'>";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr class='thead'>";
    echo "<th>User ID</th>";
    echo "<th>User Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Role</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</thead>";    

    // Array of WP_User objects.
    foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
        $user_id = $user->ID;
        $user_role = $user->roles;
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><input type="text" name="user_id" value="' . $user_id . '" readOnly="true"></td>';
        echo '<td>' . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . '</td>';
        echo '<td><select name="userRole">';
        wp_dropdown_roles( $user_role[0] );
        echo '</select></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Save">';
    echo '</form>';

    } else {
         echo "Only Administrator can see this page.";
    }

}
```

Comment: Your input names should be arrays. `<input type="text" name="user_id[]" value="' . $user_id . '" readOnly="true">`

Comment: Markus Müller just gave an answer more detailed below. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the array syntax for the input names.

```
input type="text" name="user_id[]" value="' . $user_id . '" readOnly="true">

<select name="userRole[]">
```

Your `var_dump()`calls should now output an array with all values. Then loop through your arrays using a for loop and update each user contained in the arrays.

The arrays will contain all users. If you want to only process the users where the role changed, you either have to check the old role in the for loop, or you have to add some javascript code to mark certain rows as updated

Comment: Thanks mate, its working. One more small question, the roles are changed in backend but in order to check updated results I have to refresh the page. Should I add page delay or something in the code?